# How do i use Umbraco Lucene to query site content

Tags: umbraco

I want to start using "*lucene*" to query  "*Umbraco*" content , 
What is the easiest way to get it up and running.
I tried using easy search "lucene wrapper",
It is working but i am not getting any results from the query, 
I try to delete ExamineIndexes from /App_Data/TEMP
But *Umbraco* do not create new *ExamineIndexes* file
I am using Umbraco version 7.1.8
And c#
I am trying to query the examineindexes: at the  front end

Comment: What version of umbraco are you using?
Where are you trying to query the examineindexes: the backoffice or on the front end? Are you wanting to use AngularJs or C#?
There's lot's of good documentation provided you give us more details in order to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Examine` is a `Lucene` implementation for Umbraco.

Taken from the [Umbraco documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Searching/Examine/quick-start), the following steps should help you get going with searching with `Examine` and Umbraco:

### Create an index

To create a searchable index we need to create 3 things: an Indexer a Searcher and an Index Set.

1. Open ~/Config/ExamineSettings.config and add an indexer under the 'ExamineIndexProviders/providers' section (in this example it is named ExternalIndexer):

   `<add name="ExternalIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"/>`
2. In the same file (~/Config/ExamineSettings.config) add a searcher under the 'ExamineSearchProviders/providers' section (in this example it is named ExternalSearcher):

   `<add name="ExternalSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine" />`
3. In the same file we'll change the default search provider to the one we've created, set `defaultProvider="ExternalSearcher"`
4. Open ~/Config/ExamineIndex.config and add an index set (in this example it is named `ExternalIndexSet`):

   `<IndexSet SetName="ExternalIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/External/" />`

We have a searchable index configured using Examine. Examine will detect that the index doesn't exist on the file system yet so the index will be rebuilt during application startup. Once that happens the index will automatically stay up to date with the data in Umbraco.

### Searching with Razor

In razor macros there's a `Search` method on the `DynamicNode` model which will return a `DynamicNodeList`:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["query"]))    
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var result in Umbraco.Search(Request.QueryString["query"]))
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@result.Url">@result.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: From some reason I do not have Search under Model

Comment: I have edited the solution - `Umbraco.Search(String searchTerm)` is the correct usage.